# Inductor based or switched capacitor DC-DC converter for given load parameters for mouse's headstage

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, wireless

For my master's thesis project, which focuses on designing a control loop for a DC-DC converter in the receiver of a resonant inductive coupling system to handle significant and unpredictable disturbances caused by the horizontal misalignments of a mouse, I need to choose a suitable DC-DC converter implementation based on the following load requirements:

V_load1 = 1.1 V and I_load1 = 5 mA and V_load2 = 3.3 V and I_load = ~10 uA. The input voltage would be expected to be higher than 3.3 V, even without the implementation of the power link. The DC-DC converter implementation is not my part, no other designer is designing the DC-DC converter yet, as I mainly focus on the design of the control-loop. However, the control-loop heavily depends on the DC-DC converters, so I have limited to SC-based and inductor-based DC-DC converters.

Considering the specified load values, it may seem logical to choose switched-capacitor (SC)-based DC-DC converters, especially if all the components are going to be integrated into a CMOS technology, as the entire electronics will be implemented on the mouse's headstage for small size and weight. However, what would be the disadvantages of selecting the inductor based DC-DC converter for currents in the range of microamperes to milliampers or power in milliwats?

I mostly found inductive buck converters for high currents but not in the order of microampers to several milliampers.

Comment: What is the input? What are other important parameters of this converter? Should it be very light or small? Efficient because of heat generation, available power, or just because? How does the inductive coupling system factor into its design?

Comment: Input is dc voltage at least 3.3 V, coming from the rectifier, is not designed yet. Other important parameters are high efficiency > 90% at low current ~10 uA, with. Should be light due to electronics on the mouse. The inductive coupling system has not been designed yet, as this is not my part... (project has lots of unknown implementation).